# Непонятное мигание кнопок у диалога android

Tags: android, android-dialog

Тема holo, запускаю приложение под android 5.1 AOSP и там есть диалог с текстовым полем. И почему то кнопки мигают в такт с курсором или же горят если курсор не мигает (введен текст). Вот этот зеленый цвет на кнопках да еще с растеризацией по контуру.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст инициализации диалога банальный

```
View saveasView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.save_as, null);
final EditText userInput = (EditText) saveasView.findViewById(R.id.txtFilename);

final AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
adb.setTitle(R.string.saveas);
adb.setView(saveasView);
adb.setPositiveButton(R.string.save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        ...
    }
});
// кнопка нейтрального ответа
adb.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        dialogInterface.cancel();
    }
});
// создаем диалог
return adb.create();
```

разметка

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:padding="10dp">

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/txtFilename"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="@string/labeldb_filename_hint"
      android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
      android:textColorHint="@color/colorGray">
      <requestFocus />
  </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Нет никаких стилей диалога, да и вообще никаких кроме

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
```

Почему так происходит и как его чинить?

Comment: Лучше всего использовать тему AppCompat, чем пытаться выяснить, что там случилось

Comment: @pavlofff Я так понимаю это новомодный материал. Не все его любят, несмотря на моду.